# I just installed CocoaPods and when i run my iOS application it fails to read the imported header files

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So I added for example, `#import "test/test.h"` and when I do command click on it, it goes the the `.h` file so I think it reads it. yet when I build it says cannot find `.h` file. 
I've uninstalled pods from my project and reintegrated pods few times now and still the same issue. 
Ive tried doing a clean as well.

I notice that under Frameworks in my app, `Pods_App.framwork` is red if that means its missing or  its normal?

Comment: reinstall this file from cocoapod. i had face same issue.

Comment: @Mr.Bond how can i do this?

Comment: i have posted answer check this...may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#import <test/test.h>
```

`"test/test.h"` will search the file in the current source directory whereas `<test/test.h>` searches in the header search paths

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

CocoaPods

Install CocoaPods if not already available:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
$ pod setup
```

Change to the directory of your Xcode project:

```
$ cd /path/to/MyProject
$ touch Podfile
$ edit Podfile
```

Edit your Podfile and add [COCOA pod FILE name]:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'FILE NAME'
```

Install into your Xcode project:

```
$ pod install
```

**Open your project in Xcode from the .xcworkspace file (not the usual project file)**

**if you Already install cocoa pod file, Then only open Below file:**

```
$ open MyProject.xcworkspace
```

Comment: i do have podfile installed already, it still doesnt work. i even open the .xcworkspace.

Comment: can you give me your project screenshot.?

Comment: what part? the left panel?

Comment: remove and move to trash accelerate file., and re-install via pod or add from framework. if this not work, then i can't do more. this is final.

Comment: so remove the accelerate.framework? and then do pod install?

Comment: remover and install then tell me that working or not?

Comment: got it to work, thanks, also is it normal for Pods_Appname.framework to be red?

Comment: no, sometime framework is not properly installed, then come this type of problm.

Comment: @farhan my answer is right, then mark as a Answer, give Up vote, thank you.

Comment: for some reason now, all of my imported frameworks are saying there not found.

Comment: there all the framework Remove and install , like last one.

Comment: we have to talk in personal chat?

Comment: apparently i cant cus i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: ok, don't worry. give me your skype id, we have talk in skype.

Comment: are you on the chat?

Comment: i don't have a chat option.

Comment: What should my header search paths be?

Comment: which framework do you have use?  #import <test/test.h>
add like this. in your .H file.

Comment: yes i have it like that, my question is under Build Settings what should my Header Search Paths be? should it be $(inherited)?

Comment: sorry mate, i don't understand that what are you trying to say.

Comment: Im wondering why when i install the pods, everything seems fine. i even click on the #import <test/test.h> and it goes to the .h and its saying it cant find the header file.

Comment: i don't mean its like, dont use #import<test/test.h> file, you have to use your personal pod file IMPORT file...

Comment: yes i know. im using for example #import <Parse/Parse.h> its saying it cant be found when i know its been installed.

Comment: yes, you are right, what i am recently saying that if you add framework generally then add import, but not in cocoa pod..

Comment: im doing #import in a viewcontroller.h file and its saying 'ParseUI/ParseUI.h' file not found

Comment: sorry i dont think i can provide that. are there any other suggestions you have?

Comment: is this normal? http://imgur.com/MXHpKwI its in the file path of deriveddata/app-fjkldsafklfsakjfdla/build/products/debug/pods_app.framework

Comment: you can't Access this file, its lock file from pod.

Answer (score 0):

Quite Xcode and open your .xcworkspace again and try to import like this:

```
#import <test.h>
```